# Do we need to wait or flush user events or property before fetching remote config in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

Do we need to wait or flush user events or property before fetching remote config in Firebase in order to get the correct one?

Here's my setup: 
I have two apps that shares the same Firebase app. The reason they share the same app is that I need to track conversion between the two apps, and can't find any better way!?

So I've created a **User Propery**, "Is_Lite_Version", and will create an AB for a remote config.

On launch, the app will both set the **User Propery** and fetch remote config.

My question is, could there be a problem here, due to latency? Where the remote config is fetch before the **User Propery** has been set, and then not getting the correct value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm interested in knowing will the remote config and in my case the A/B test conditions react fast enough to user properties set upon first app launch. Did you find any answer to this?